# Client-Side Equivalent of drupal_set_message with javascript

Tags: 7, javascript

I've got javascript that notifies the user of actions and errors, and I'd like to use the existing Drupal messaging. Is this built in to Drupal?

Alternatively, (I'm fairly new to Drupal and am not very familiar with the modules available) if this is available as a module, I haven't been able to find it. Does anyone know of a module?

UPDATE: To clarify, I'm trying to set a Drupal message from the client-side (JavaScript), on a page that has already rendered. This is a very AJAXy page with tonnes of functionality that sometimes requires messages be shown to the user.

Is there is a provision in the Drupal client-side API for setting messages?

Comment: hello. I do not know if others, but to me your question is not all clear (sorry). do you want show messages from a module of Drupal using javascript?

Comment: Can you post some of your javascript code?

Comment: @Martin Schlagnitweit This is legacy js that I'm porting into Drupal... the legacy code is kind of irrelevant -- it just manually created it's own message in the old system.

Comment: If there is nothing in the client-side API for this, I guess this is a good candidate for a new module?!

Comment: @moon.watcher I want to show messages from JavaScript. Incidentally, this js is part of a module, but I don't think that's relevant in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see JS API for dispaying messages even in D7. Maybe because all you need is `DIV` with classes like `messages`,`status` `warning` or `error`. You can see how drupal works with it in file `/misc/tabledrag.js`.
When you drag rows in tables drupal shows you a warning message with this code:

```js
$(Drupal.theme('tableDragChangedWarning')).insertBefore(self.table).hide().fadeIn('slow');
```

Comment: Okay, that's it then... I smell a new module coming on to reduce duplicate code...
Thanks @kalabro